# how can I add a image in flutter

Tags: image, flutter

I have a problem with adding image... my code is

```
 child: Column(
             
                children: [
                Image.asset('assets/logo.jpg'),
                Text('This is SplashScreen')
]
),
```

but didn't work yet..I also enabled pubspec.yamel assets commnet but did'nt change anything

Answer (score 0):

Add the path of the image in the pubspec file after the asset tag like this:

```
  assets:
    - assets/ilustration/b1.png
```

and then rebuild your application

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have an assets folder in the main tree, not nested inside another folder.